# Place caption at bottom of table?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I found [this](https://orgmode.org/manual/Tables-in-HTML-export.html) which would seemingly indicate that you just run

```
(setq org-html-table-caption-above nil)
```

if you want the caption to appear *below* the table. But it doesn't. How can I make the caption appear *below* the table

```
#+CAPTION: A table caption  
#+ATTR_HTML: :border 2 :rules all :frame border
|---+---+---+---+---+---|
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
|---+---+---+---+---+---|
| T | T | F | T | F | T |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |
|---+---+---+---+---+---|
```

Comment: Works for me. Check the value of the variable with `C-h v org-html-table-caption-above` to make sure that your setting has "taken".

Comment: Also if you are checking the page in your browser, don't forget to refresh it !-)

Comment: Yes, and for me when I do a emacs -Q it's fine. I looked through my init-world and couldn't find anything that should countermand the setq. So I just changed my custom CSS to include `caption.t-bottom {...caption-side: bottom}`. I'm on 9.6 while the default clean is 9.5.5(?).

Comment: You are papering over the problem this way. The best thing to do is bisect your inif tile and find out exactly what is causing the problem.

Comment: Will do. And report.